# How to order coordinates from top left to bottom right?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of class objects my_rectangle:

```
class my_rectangle:
    def __init__(self,text,x_start,y_start,x_end,y_end):
        self.text=text
        self.x_start=x_start
        self.y_start=y_start
        self.x_end=x_end
        self.y_end=y_end
        self.x_centroid=(self.x_start+self.x_end)/2
        self.y_centroid=(self.y_start+self.y_end)/2
```

Using the class attributes (`x_centroid` and `y_centroid`) which give the coordinates of the centroid, I wanted to order this list, using as an order left-to-right then top-to-bottom (normal English reading order)?

Say I have:

```
A=my_rectangle('Hi,',1,3,2,4)
B=my_rectangle('Im',3,3,3,4)
C=my_rectangle('New',1,1,2,2)
my_list=[C,B,A]
```

And I want to order it to get:

```
my_sorted_list=[A,B,C]
```

Which is a representation of the text:

```
""" Hi, I'm
    New 
"""
```

Answer (score 4):

Generating a sorted list is the specialty of the builtin function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Sorting using multiple values can be accomplished by providing a `key` function, which key function returns the values as a tuple. The resulting list is then sorted according to the lexicographical ordering of the tuple.

```
#UNTESTED
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda item: (item.x_centroid, item.y_centroid))
```

Comment: Hi. But would this order from top left to bottom right?

Answer (score 3):

You can make custom classes sortable by defining a `__lt__` method. This takes care of the `<` operator which is used in default sorting.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,text,x_start,y_start,x_end,y_end):
        self.text=text
        self.x_start=x_start
        self.y_start=y_start
        self.x_end=x_end
        self.y_end=y_end

    @property
    def centroid(self):
        return (self.x_start+self.x_end)/2, (self.y_start+self.y_end)/2

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """Using "reading order" in a coordinate system where 0,0 is bottom left"""
        try:
            x0, y0 = self.centroid
            x1, y1 = other.centroid
            return (-y0, x0) < (-y1, x1)
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Rectangle: ' + self.text
```

I'm defining `centroid` as a property, so that it will update if you change any of the other coordinates after initializing a Rectangle.

You will get this output if you use the data from your question.

```
>>> rectangles = [
...     Rectangle('A',1,3,2,4),
...     Rectangle('B',3,3,3,4),
...     Rectangle('C',1,1,2,2), 
... ]
>>> print(sorted(rectangles))
[Rectangle: A, Rectangle: B, Rectangle: C]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually im looking for top left to bottom right order, as if reading. Your solution provides a bottom left to top right.

Comment: That depends on the coordinate system. In computer graphics, the 0,0 point is conventionally in the top left corner. So if you want a different coordinate system, it's trivial to change the `__lt__` method. You didn't mention which coordinate system you are using.

Comment: I've updated my answer, so that you will get reading order in a coordinate system where 0,0 is bottom left

Comment: Worked great. One last question. Say there was an small difference (epsilon) in the y coordinates so that the algorithm calculates they are on a different line, whereas this difference is imperceptible enough for us to think the points lie on the same line. Given Rectangle('D',3,1.01,4,2.01) , the version currently outputs [A,B,D,C] whereas it should be [A,B,C,D] since rectangle D lies to the right of C, and same y coordinate (except possibly the small difference 0.01)

Comment: Use [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) on the centroid coordinates.